# tomcat dns forwarding to multiple applications

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, tomcat, forwarding

I recently installed business objects software on tomcat 6. I have 2 domains - domain1 and domain2. This software allows access to two of its applications via these URLS:

ADDRESS:http://myservername.domain1:8080/BO/APP1 and ADDRESS:http://myservername.domain1:8080/BO/APP2.

Instead of these urls, I would like the end users to access these apps via something like http://bobj.domain2.com:8080/BO/APP1 and http://bobj.domain2.com:8080/BO/APP2.

I cannot figure out how to accomplish that. I have looked into the option of http redirect (not good because the destination address shows up in the address bar), domain forwarding (not sure if it would work with multiple applications and forwarding from one domain to another) and also using apache tomcat with mod_jk by using virtual hosts (not sure if it is possible when forwarding from one domain to a sub domain in another domain) ??

please advise as to what would be my best option and how to accomplish.

thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

So you already have 2 .COM domains and are using hosted DNS? You need to create a DNS CNAME record for your subdomains. See here: content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm

Comment: yes I can create DNS CNAME records like app1.domain2.com and app2.domain2.com but how do I forward those to my applications on tomcat ?

Comment: You need to create a virtualhost for the subdomain. See here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html